# Solr - Facet terms and Synonyms

Tags: solr

**Question:** 
Is there a way to get the synonyms for the faceted terms?

**Background:** I have terms which I am building a facet with. These terms have synonyms, and I can get both the terms and synonyms highlighted.

**What I am trying to do:** What I would like to do is get the synonyms for each term to display or at least extract them somehow to use in another interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think there is a way within Solr to retrieve synonyms for display (outside of highlighting), as they are only expanded for indexing.

That said, it wouldn't be hard (in Solr or in your DB) to build a lookup index/table to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you would like, but if you have a version of Solr which is quite recent, then you can use managed synonyms to easily get the list of the different synonyms:
[Managed resources](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Resources)
 And then combine it with regular queries to finally get what you want.